# How to make my apps statusbar look like google maps?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-toolbar

Does anyone know how to make statusbar look like google maps?

[image]

[image]

I manage to get transparent status for my drawer layout 
using `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` and

`<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
 <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>`

layout -> activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">...
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_main_header" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

values-v21 -> styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android transparent status bar and actionbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907615/android-transparent-status-bar-and-actionbar)

Answer (score 2):

You may do it using themes:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

Or programmatically:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
```

For more information you may read:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#UI
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION