# How to hide status bar during splashscreen

Tags: android, ionic2

I am beginner in ionic 2.

How to hide status bar when showing splashscreen in android platform.

Here is my component.

app opened show splashscreen.and does not changes the status bar color.

splashscreen hide.after changes the status bar color.

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
   this.Status.backgroundColorByHexString("#0e5591");
      Splashscreen.hide();
})
```

I need changes status bar color during splashscreen when showing.

Kindly advice me.

Thanks

Comment: Make activity full screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android transparent status bar and actionbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907615/android-transparent-status-bar-and-actionbar)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.my app opened.show splashscreen and.does not change the statusbar color.and same time hide splashscreen.after changes the status bar color.I need show splashscreen with status bar color change.

Comment: Not understanding your question properly, can you please make it clear? @Anivaishu

Comment: @Pratik Dasa  . I update my question.Kindly check it.

Comment: Sorry I dont know about ionic, I am a native android developer. @Anivaishu you can drop me an email if you want any help in native.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to set statusbar color programmatically:

```
 Window window = getWindow();
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.transparent));
}
```

Comment: Thank u for u reply.I cannot understand ur answer.I am using ionic 2.and also updated my question.kindly help me.

Comment: @Anivaishu first not mentioned that the que is for ionic that is why some mis communication happened to me and I think to Mayura also.

Comment: @suraj can u help me.. how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Android, adding following in `styles.xml` changes status bar color. (I'm showing status bar with white background)

```xml
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```