# Calculate Android screen size

Tags: android, screen-size

I have this piece of code :

```
    Point point = new Point();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(point);
    setScreenSize(point);
```

This returns the total height of the display in pixels.
However, this includes the notification bar and, on some devices, the bottom bar that contains the android-specific buttons (back, home and that other one).

My question is a two-parter.

How can I find out the height of the notification bar?
How can I find if the device has those buttons on the screen, and if it does, what is the height of that bar?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to just get the dimensions of the layout/container you are working in?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407256/height-of-status-bar-in-android

Comment: I also have to get that, but that I know how to do. I need the exact app height.

Comment: It is not the status bar that I need, the small notification tray right above that

Answer (score 2):

**You can try these.I recently used below code in one of my projects. It works**

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
String displayName = display.getName();  // minSdkVersion=17+
Log.i(TAG, "displayName  = " + displayName);
```

**// display size in pixels**

```
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
Log.i(TAG, "width        = " + width);
Log.i(TAG, "height       = " + height);
```

**// get in (pixels or dpi)**

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int heightPixels = metrics.heightPixels;
int widthPixels = metrics.widthPixels;
int densityDpi = metrics.densityDpi;
```

**// this one is deprecated**

```
int screenHeight = display.getHeight();
int screenWidth = display.getWidth();
Log.i(TAG, "screenHeight = " + screenHeight);
Log.i(TAG, "screenWidth  = " + screenWidth);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot of the default Android specifications such as StatusBar (Metrics & Keylines) and NavBar (Structure) in the Android Material Design Specification...

I believe that status bar is 24dp and NavBar is 48dp as standard.

You can get the width and height in DP by using:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

float screenWidthDP = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
float screenHeightDP = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
```

[Material Design Specification](https://www.google.co.uk/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
Display mDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point mPoint = new Point();
mDisplay.getSize(mPoint);
int width = mPoint.x;
int height = mPoint.y;
```

Hope this will help you.