# How to get the height of the status bar in Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova

I'm using this plugin (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar) to handle the status bar within my application and I chose to use it over the application, however, need to know how high the bar occupies the screen for the application is set to make visually beautiful.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You will need a native plugin for that. This may help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407256/height-of-status-bar-in-android

Comment: But where I put these codes and to make it possible for me to access the result within the app? I do not know much about android programming =p