# What actual viewport size are the Samsung S6 and Samsung S7 mobile phones?

Tags: android, css, viewport, samsung-mobile

I am trying to optimise for the latest and newest Samsung models.

For the S5 the Display is 1080x1920 with a 432 dpi resolution, this is 3dppx. This translates to a 360x640w viewport.

Is there a way to work out the viewport if you only have the display and resolution details only?

Answer (score 1):

The viewport of a Galaxy s6 and s7 is the same as an s5 but I don't know how to calculate it.
The view port is 360 x 640 px

(which means if you visit [whatismyscreenresolution.com](http://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com/), it will report screen size 360 x 640)

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on the browser user's are using.

Chrome frame consumes around 60px, so given the status bar will be 25px, you can assume you have 85px less than the actual size.

I would recommend using JavaScript `window.innerHeight` for proper measurement.

Sources:
- https://mydevice.io/devices/
- [Height of status bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407256/height-of-status-bar-in-android)