# Is there a way to get Android status bar height with QtQuick?

Tags: android, qml, qtquick2

Is there any way? `Screen.height - Screen.desktopAvailableHeight` seems to work, but will it work everywhere?

Comment: I think this is only possible when using native android calls within your qt application: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407256/height-of-status-bar-in-android