# android PopupMenu showAtLocation y offset

Tags: android, popupwindow

Does anyone know why when I use this code:

```
popupMenu.showAtLocation(containerView, Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.LEFT, x_offset, y_offset);
```

The y offset doesn't actually move the popup until it's greater than a certain number (in this case approx 120). For values under 120, nothing happens; for values over 120, the popup moves vertically up.

I'm guessing it's to do with the size of the popup, for which there doesn't seem to be a way to actually get the dimensions of to compensate for this threshold.

I'd like to know because a) there's scant information about this method, and b) I can't seem to get it to work to position my popup correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty old question but I would like to mention here that in case if anyone else is wondering what is the threshold for the yOffset - it is the top insets of the view you are passing to the `showAtLocation()` method.
In most cases this is your system bar height.

You can try to calculate the `yOffset` by

```
int desiredOffsetPx = 250;
int yOffset = desiredOffsetPx + systemWindowInsetTop
popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, yOffset)
```

In order to get `systemWindowInsetTop` please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47125610/5990959)

Answer (score 0):

```
void showAtLocation (View parent, 
            int gravity, 
            int x, 
            int y)
```

Display the content view in a popup window at the specified location. If the popup window cannot fit on screen, it will be clipped. See [WindowManager.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html) for more information on how gravity and the x and y parameters are related. Specifying a gravity of NO_GRAVITY is similar to specifying Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP.

You can find whole detail on this link : [deveoper.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#showAtLocation(android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20int))