# statusbar has a white line?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Here is my layout， Why is there a white line between the status bar and the title? How do I remove this white line。
I made an album, but found white lines in the nested layout. I didn't search for relevant content on Google, so I posted a post for you to look at. Here are my code and screenshots.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/image_display_color">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/surface_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">
        <com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
            android:id="@+id/big_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <!-- toolbar -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="#80000000">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:contentDescription="TODO"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/video_back" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- 播放进度-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:id="@+id/layout_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:alpha="0.9"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_share"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="分享"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_baseline_share_24"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_favaite"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="收藏"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_baseline_favorite_24"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_copy"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="复制"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_copy_white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="删除"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_baseline_delete_24"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_more"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_baseline_more_vert_24"
            android:text="更多"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my screenshot。

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJUGu.jpg)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2TJz.jpg)

Comment: In your LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_top", remove the marginTop

Comment: thank you, the margintop is statusbar height ,Remove the status bar, and the title will be moved to the status bar。

Answer (score 0):

The "line" is because your dark overlay doesn't exactly line up with the top of your content/bottom of the status bar. There's a gap where the content shows through:

[image: A crop of the image showing where the overlay shim doesn't cover the photos beneath]

You can see the photos through that gap. I'm assuming this layout is overlaid on the entire screen, and you're using `layout_marginTop="30dp"` to try and move it below the status bar? That's going to have problems - the size of the bar depends on the device. On stock Android (following [Material Design guidelines](https://material.io/design/platform-guidance/android-bars.html#status-bar)) the status bar is *24dp*. On your device, it's obviously close to *30dp* - but not exactly! That's why it doesn't line up.

---

I think making this work perfectly is going to be difficult. If I were you, I wouldn't try to overlay the entire screen. If you use a `NoActionBar` theme, and add a `Toolbar` into your layout instead, then you can add your overlay in the same layout. You can cover the `Toolbar` if you like, and the top of the `Activity`/`Fragment` will be below the status bar.

But it looks like you're making some kind of overlay over other apps - in that case, have a look at this thread for some ideas about getting the current device's status bar height (if any): [Height of status bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3407256/13598222)

Comment: Yes, I set the height When the top is 30dp, the white line will appear, but when I set it to 29.7dp, the white line will disappear. The height of the status bar I obtained is 78px. If the dp is converted to the int type, it is 30dp. If the dp is converted to the float type, it is actually 29.7 dp However, I found that the float type cannot be set through Java. Do you know of any other methods?

Comment: Different devices have different height of status bar, unless the height is dynamically set by means of programming code.

Comment: @jeesk You can set the `margin_top` value in code: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams#setMargins(int,%20int,%20int,%20int) and that takes a pixel value. So if you've determined your status bar is *78px* high, you can just set that exact value on your `layout_top` `LinearLayout`. No need to mess around with *dp* values and do conversions, and worry about rounding errors!