# System bar size on android tablets

Tags: android, size, tablet

I've got the problem that I need the height of the android tablet system bar. It's the same problem as over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173926/screen-size-honeycomb-menu-android), but I cant use this answer, because it gives me the same size as from the DisplayMetrics. At both ways I get the resolution with this bar allready calculated in it. (This problem doesnt appear at my smartphone, just on my tablet).

Answer (score 11):

```
// status bar (at the top of the screen on a Nexus device) 
public static int getStatusBarHeight(Context context) {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return 0;
}

// navigation bar (at the bottom of the screen on a Nexus device)
public static int getNavigationBarHeight(Context context) {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: both your methods are exactly the same

Comment: @Frank - Different values are passed as the first argument to `getIdentifier()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8367739/807499

It gives the full height of the screen. You can then minus the size given by DisplayMetrics or by your root layout's size.

Answer (score 0):

Chris Banes mentioned this in a recent Droidcon talk. The whole talk is super relevant, but here's a link to the part that answers your question (for all form factors, including tablet).

https://youtu.be/_mGDMVRO3iE?t=1093

This is the correct way to get status bar and navigation bar sizes: [setOnApplyWindowListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View,%20android.support.v4.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener))

I hope this helps!