# SystemBar width on tablets

Tags: android

After lurking a lot for all kind of responses (thanks for this awesome website), I ask my first question. Forgive me if I do anything wrong!

I wanted to know if there's a way to find the width of the systembar on Android tablets. Not the part with virtual buttons (Back, Home, Menu...), the clickable part popping all the notifications messages.

And also if there's an easy way to know if the systembar/statusbar is on top or bottom. From other responses on that matter, getDecorView doesn't seem reliable in all cases.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few relevant questions that might help you [Height of statusbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355367/height-of-statusbar/3356263#3356263) and 
[System bar size on android tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165563/system-bar-size-on-android-tablets)

In many cases you won't need to know the location of the system bar, and to draw your custom components correctly (i.e. to not be covered by the system bar) all what you need is to override the `fitSystemWindows` as shown below:

(note the comment: *when insets.top > 0 you can expect the system bar to be in the top and similarly when insets.bottom > 0*)

```
@Override
protected boolean fitSystemWindows(Rect insets) {

    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) this
            .getLayoutParams();

    int top = params.topMargin + insets.top;
    int bottom = params.bottomMargin + insets.bottom;
    int left = params.leftMargin + insets.left;
    int right = params.rightMargin + insets.right;  
    /* Usually when insets.top > 0 means the systembar on the top and simiarly if insets.bottom > 0*/
    params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer seems to respond well to the second part of my question. I did not test yet but since it's been the only response in 3months and it seems very pertinent I validate it now.