# Wrong view size returned in onGlobalLayout

Tags: android, view, statusbar

I have an app where a user takes a picture or chooses a picture from the gallery.  On the next page, I use `onGlobalLayout` to determine the size of a `View`.  When the user picks a picture from the gallery, the `View` size is returned correctly in `onGlobalLayout`.  However, when a user takes a picture, the `Status Bar` at the top is made invisible.  When the next activity appears, the `Status Bar` slides in from the top which changes the screen size but the `onGlobalLayout` does not account for this and therefore returns the wrong size of the view.

This appears to be a bug with Android and I am considering filing a bug report. However, does anyone have any workarounds for this?

Example:

```
public class MyView extends View implements OnGlobalLayoutListener {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Log.d("MyView", "Width: " + getWidth());
        Log.d("MyView", "Height: " + getHeight());
    }
}
```

The above code will return two different widths and heights depending on if the screen I am returning from has a status bar or not.

Thanks

Comment: Difficult to suggest fixes or workarounds without any code as a starting point. But I assume there's some reason you can't post any?

Comment: I've added a basic example of OnGlobalLayoutListener...however, I cant post the full code since it would be too much (and I'm not allowed ;))

Comment: can you add the xml so that we can see this view in the layout?

Comment: It's just a very basic relative layout with 'fill_parent' layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `fitSystemWindows` in your view to get the size of the `StatusBar` and calculate your view size accordingly, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804463/systembar-width-on-tablets) for an example.

Another solution, but less generic and more cumbersome, is to adjust the size according a predefined list of [status bar heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600713/size-of-android-notification-bar-and-title-bar), since android have a fixed size for the status bar according to the device screen density.

I do not think it is a bug in android.

Comment: I can find the height of the status bar, however, in some cases the status bar is there, and in some cases it is not.  I could send data in the bundle to let the new activity know where it's coming from, however, I'd rather avoid this if possible.