# HVGA shows different screen size in emulator in android 4.3?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, screen-size

I am trying to develop an app of HVGA [320 x 480] its showing the same size in android 2.3 but the screen size varies in android 4.3 it shows 320 x 432 in the log.Any reason for it.please help me on this.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference of 48 pixels is taken up by the system bar.

Comment: What is the issue? When you design the app, you should consider that, in devices with Honeycomb and above, there is a system bar and only the remaining space is available for your app.

Comment: When I tried to design it for tablet of screen size 1280 x 720,I ended up in getting its screens size 1184 x 720.How to find the actual area the system bar would occupy on the screen.Any ratio for it with screen actual size.

Comment: You should rarely be depending on the absolute values of the screen height and width. In case you need to, you can check out this question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7213771/1321873

Comment: I tried many of the methods but yet I couldn't find a way to get total screen size & system bar size seprately..Could you please help me on it..

Comment: It does not fit the scope of your OP. If the existing answers don't satisfy your requirements, post it as a new question with the effort you have made (code snippets that you have tried). May be you will get better response.