# Android - size (and names) of screen componants

Tags: android, wallpaper

I'm sure this will have been asked before, but I don't know how to look it up because I don't know the names of the things I'm looking for...

I'm making a live wallpaper and have a canvas which covers the *whole* screen. At the top of the screen, there is a bar containing tiny icons and I need to know how many pixels this is occupying because I want to avoid having the top of my displayed image being chopped off. What is this bar called, and how tall is it?

Also at the bottom of the screen there is another bar containing bigger icons - it can be scrolled sideways. What is this called and how tall is it?

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, I have seen the top bar described as a title bar, a status bar and a notification bar! I still don't know which is correct... but I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462266/height-of-title-bar-from-a-live-wallpaper?lq=1) question which answers the most important part of my question.