# Record Android screen change steps and playback

Tags: android, user-interface, audiovideoplayback

I want to save the screen changes (events) in an Android screen. And then play it back when needed.

Recording should not be in video mode but step wise (somewhat like UI testing)

Can anyone tell how to proceed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android screenshot of activity with actionbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194118/android-screenshot-of-activity-with-actionbar)