# OnTouchEvent isn't sure where drawRect is

Tags: java, android

I have a Rect object which I draw using drawRect(Rect, Paint). I have a OnTouchEvent that checks if the touch position is inside the Rect. If the touch is inside the Rect then something on my screen changes.
The issue I'm having is: Where I have to touch to get the on touch statements to execute is around 50 pixels higher than the Rect object.

Here is the relevant parts of my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    DrawView drawView;
    RelativeLayout fLY;
    static Rect newGame = new Rect(LEFT, 165 + 35, 320, 200 + 35);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        fLY = new RelativeLayout(this);
        drawView = new DrawView(this);
        fLY.addView(drawView);
        setContentView(fLY);
    }

    @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int touchX = (int)event.getX();
        int touchY = (int)event.getY();
        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if(newGame.contains(touchX, touchY))reset();
        }
    }
```

And my DrawView class:

```
public class DrawView extends View{
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    int COLORS[] = Constants.COLORS;
    int left = 250;
    int size = 35;

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);   
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRect(MainActivity.newGame, paint);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably off by exactly the height of the Status Bar. You can get the height of the status bar through this answer: [Height of statusbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355367/height-of-statusbar/3356263#3356263)

Then add that to your `getY` and it should work.

Comment: The height of the status bar and/or title bar were the issue. But when I ran the code in your link it said that status and title bar height equals zero so I was not able to fix my problem by offsetting the on touch yPos. I put the code at the end of my onCreate method. I have temporarily fixed my issue by removing the title and status bar altogether.