# Height of status bar in Android with no Activity (IME)

Tags: android, statusbar, ime

I am trying to determine the height to the status bar in Android, .  I have found answers, but all seem to rely on the Activity object ( e.g., activity.getWindow() ).  However, I am developing an input method, which does not have an associated activity object.

Any ideas how I can do this in an IME?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered in other posts. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3355367/1973326) and a response linked to [here](http://mrtn.me/blog/2012/03/17/get-the-height-of-the-status-bar-in-android/).

```
public int getStatusBarHeight() {
  int result = 0;
  int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
  if (resourceId > 0) {
      result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  The thing I didn't get for this answer is that an InputMethodService can also have an onCreate method (the sample code I was using did not explicitely define one). The second link you gave had the clue I needed.