# Android LiveWallpaper: start rendering below notification bar

Tags: android, notifications, libgdx, draw, live-wallpaper

I'm doing a Android LiveWallpaper with LibGDX and I want my application to start rendering below the notification bar, and not under it. 
In the picture: Left is what I get, right what I want. Any advice? Thanks
[image: problem]

Comment: Is it not possible to get the height of the status bar, and add padding to the view accordingly? The answers to the following question might help: [Height of status bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355367/height-of-statusbar)

Comment: are you using a static view port for all devices?

Comment: @zappp do you have some issues with this again or why did you unaccept my answer? If you run into any issue please update your question and mybe someone can help you. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this: [Height of Android statusbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407256/height-of-status-bar-in-android)

And simply draw under it. If you are using Worldunit based drawing (not Pixelbased) you can use this:

```
Gdx.gl.glViewport(x, statusbar.height, width, height);
```

To show you what this does look at  this link: [Keep aspect with black borders](http://blog.acamara.es/2012/02/05/keep-screen-aspect-ratio-with-different-resolutions-using-libgdx/)

Comment: Doesn' this help you anymore?

Comment: It does help, but you can't actually get the height of status bar with the getWindow method because it's only for a Activity, on a LiveWallpaperService you need to do some tricky one. It's a good answer though. Thanks to you

Comment: If you tell me how to get the height of the status bar i can update the answer.