# Toolbar in MapFragment sits underneath status bar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Seems to be a unique case compared to other similar situations, but I have a map fragment within a FrameLayout that has a "translucent" toolbar and status bar (darker, transparent color).

I put in the top container

> android:fitsSystemWindows="false"

as suggested in other posts, and that works in my other activities, but with my map fragment it doesn't.

I want the map to take up the whole screen, and slide under the status bar, and I want the toolbar to sit just below the status bar. I add some margin to the top of the toolbar in hopes to push it down below the status bar, but it maintains a gap between it and the status bar, plus it's unreliable to set a straight top margin without knowing the exact height of the status bar on a device.

In the first image, I don't have a margin_top set. In the second, you can see the gap, and if you look closely, you can see where the status bar background is in relation to the status items, it's touching them on the bottom as if it's being pushed up.
[image]
[image]

## activity_layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#59000000"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"/>
```

## activity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); // Make to run your application only in portrait mode
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.status_bar_dark));

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    }
    ...}
```

## styles.xml

```
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: I realize now that it isn't creating a "gap" but it actually looks like one of the views is beginning to overlap?

Comment: use `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't keep my content behind the status bar like I want, and it also no longer sits the map behind the device buttons.

Comment: you have to dynamically calculate height of  status bar and set top margin.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3356263/9186864
use it after `onCreate` method