# Status Bar Height in Full Screen Activity

Tags: android, margin, statusbar

I have a full screen activity in my application. I want my page title to be positioned under status bar. How can I measure status bar height in a full screen activity?

I researched about it and tried them. One of them is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37721762/8576293), which is using an attribute in xml that doen't work in my case. The other one is [Second Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407256/height-of-status-bar-in-android)

```
    val rectangle = Rect()

    window.decorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectangle)
    val statusBarHeight = rectangle.top
```

`statusBarHeight` is 0, because it's a full screen activity probably. Any help to position my some elements like title below status bar staff?

Answer (score 10):

I found the answer finally :))

```
     val statusBarHeightId = resources.getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android")

     val statusBarHeight = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(statusBarHeightId)
```

`statusBarHeight` is what I want.

Comment: Is it in dp? or px?

Answer (score -2):

Try   `android:layout_marginTop="@android:dimen/status_bar_height"`

and you can also get the [status height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355367/height-of-statusbar)  programmatically.

Comment: I get error `AAPT: error: resource android:dimen/status_bar_height is private.`

Comment: try to get it programmatically